# Where do Hapi User Credential objects come from?

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I am using Hapi.js to build a simple site with role based authorisation (i.e., Users can see *these* routes, but Managers can see *those* routes). From what I've read, it sounds like Hapi's Scopes would be ideal for this.

However, while I know how to specify a route so that it requires a certain scope, the documentation is vague on how I specify what scopes a user has. How do I specify this? What's the lifetime of these objects? Are they sent with every request? Is there tie-in with the claims used in JWTs?

I've read the [Hapi API Docs](http://hapijs.com/api), and I've read [this article about using scopes for role based authorisation.](https://blog.andyet.com/2015/06/16/harnessing-hapi-scopes/)

I'm doing the Authentication using hapi-auth-jwt2, if that suggests anything.

TLDR; How do I specify the scopes to which a user has access?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this answer is only valid for hapi-auth-jwt2. That said:

User credential object are per client request. By default, they contain whatever is in the claims in your JWT (i.e. credentials == decoded). If you want to override that behaviour, or add any additional stuff in to the credential object, you do that in your validateFunc. ValidateFunc takes a callback, and the third parameter is what you want the credentials object to be. For instance, if your user roles are in a "userRole" claim in your JWT, here's how you'd add it into your credentials.scope:

```
// in server.register()
server.auth.strategy("jwt", "jwt", {
    key: publicKey, 
    validateFunc: validate, 
    verifyOptions: {
    algorithms: ["RS256"]
        } 
});

// elsewhere
function validate(decoded, request, callback) {
    decoded.scope = decoded.userRole;
    return callback(null, true, decoded);
};
```

That's it. hapi-auth-jwt2 manages the rest. Now, in your server.route() calls, if you set the config object to:

```
config: {
    auth: {
        strategy: "jwt",
        scope: ["Manager", "Developer"]
    }
}
```

...then only requests with JWTs that have either of those strings in their userRole claim will be able to access that route.